# Create swap partition

Tags: release-freya, system-installation, dual-boot, swap

I have an old pc (Dual core, 2gb ram (No graphic card because now is damaged) I used Windows 10 just for Work (My creative cloud subscription) and thanks to the subreddit [/r/unixporn][1 I've installed Freya (my first time in linux) and now I love linux and that OS. but when I installed Elementary OS Freya I did not create the swap partition (I did not know almost nothing about linux and so install it) but now my pc stays stuck in certain times and according to I have read on websites the swap memory help the computers with low ram memory (2gb or less) the question is:

How I can create the swap memory without installing elementary os again?

I have 4gb free space for the swap memory.

The swap memory it can cause problem with the windows 10 installation?

Hope that you help me, Im newbie in linux

Comment: please add screenshot of your partition table (use `gparted`).Also what you mean "done" ? Solved your problem ? =)

Comment: @Ravan I follow the step in the tutorial of askubuntu and work fine but the 4gb of the swap was of my 30gb of the harddrive and not of the 4gb that I Created for that, now in gparted look like this: [Pic of my gparted](http://i.imgur.com/LaktGgJ.png)

Comment: Please follow my answer..

Comment: @Ravan is it the only way? at this time I don't have the usb of my distro because I lend it to a friend

Comment: follow my answer...and let me know..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer is after the discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30459/discussion-between-ravan-and-revod)

Here you have to do two things ,

1 . Deleting the /swapspace file created using [AU question](https://askubuntu.com/a/566750/452466).
2 . Creating `swap` in unallocated space.

1 . Open terminal and run the commands:

```
sudo swapoff /swapspace
sudo rm /swapspace
```

2 .  Install gparted,

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

**Note** Careful while selecting partition.

Open gparted and select **unallocated space.**

Right click on it , select `new`

Then select `file system` as `linux-swap` and `logical partition`(If not possible select `primary partition`)

Then , right click on partition and make `swapon`

**Note** Don't forget to **apply changes**

You can verify swap by the command

```
cat /proc/swaps
```

Next, add the following line to /etc/fstab to activate the new swap at boot:

```
/dev/sdb3 none swap defaults 0 0
```

(Replace `/dev/sdb3` with your swap partition)

Comment: That is for created the swap partition right? I already have the swap partition then do the tutorial from askubuntu, now I want is those 4 gb I have unused assign them to my linux harddrive and get a little more of space

Comment: @Revod does my answer created swap in un-allocated place?

Comment: @Revod I don't see swap in your `gpated` screenshot

Comment: here a pic of my system monitor, and in the therminal: sudo swapon -s http://imgur.com/a/YhiEc. But now I have 4gb free and I want to "combine" with my current primary disk to have a little more

Comment: @Revod what is output of `sudo fdisk -l` please add to question.

Comment: @Revod please let me know have you created swap using my answer , since there is no swap visible [here](http://i.imgur.com/LaktGgJ.png)

Comment: I tell you that my swap work with I use the tutorial of askubuntu in the post I write: Done, I used that tutorial: *here the link of askubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/a/566750/452466*, but I don't know why in gparted don't appear the swap. Sorry, im a newbie using linux

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30459/discussion-between-ravan-and-revod).